# What is the name of the cascading view of all apps in android home (see attached pic)?

Tags: android, android-activity

When you click right most button in Andorid you see this

[image]

1. What is the name of this view?
2. When you swipe each app to right,
       What happens?
3. What is the state of the activity (that was going
       through) when you swipe it right)?

Answer (score 1):

That is called the **Overview Screen** (aka recents screen, recent task list, or recent apps) - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html

When you swipe an app to the side and remove it from the list, it kills any background or empty processes the application is currently running, and then possibly kill the services that are running depending on if you set the `onTaskRemoved()` callback ( more info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent) ).  By default it does *not* remove any running services, though.

Things like Alarms, PendingIntents and Notifications will not be removed just by sliding the app closed in the overview screen.  That only happens if a user does a **force stop** on the application (in the phones main Application Settings).

If the app was previously put into the background from pushing the home button or opening another app, then its state would be a background process and the last activity states in its lifecycle would be `onPause()` followed by `onStop()`, then when you swipe it to the side `onDestroy()` is called.